# Is there a increaseIndentPattern in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm trying to add auto increate indentation feature in a Sublime Text package.
As for TextMate, there's `increaseIndentPattern = '\{';` that can make easy indentation.
http://manual.macromates.com/en/appendix#indentation_rules
How can I do that in SUblime Text?

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text 2 already has easy indentation built in.

Hit `Ctrl+]` to indent right, and `Ctrl+[` to indent back or remove indentation.

Similarly, you can select the text you want to indent, and hit the `Tab` key. This indents the selected block of text. `Shift+Tab` will remove indentation of selected text.

If you are working with predefined syntaxes you can [define a keybinding](https://gist.github.com/JLMorales/6080845) for your "ReIndent" command, which will execute *Edit>Line>Reindent* command on the entire document.

However, if you reeeeally want to get your hands dirty with setting up how the program indents specific language syntaxes, you go to the *Preferences* Menu and hit *Browse Packages*.

Look for the language you want to modify indentation rules for, I'll use PHP as an example. There are 2 files that have indentation rules for my copy of PHP right now. Their names are as follows:

1. Indentation Rules Annex.tmPreferences
2. Indentation Rules.tmPreferences

There should be another copy of these same filenames with *.cache at the end. Feel free to add .old after .cache and modify the plain *.tmPreferences ones.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is `*.tmPreferences` file is difficult to read due to the lack of docs.

Comment: Indeed. That is why, when faced with this issue, I just settled with ReIndent 'ing with the F12 key using the keybinding I linked above.

Comment: For reference, I found [unofficial tmPreferences documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/metadata.html). According to a link on the [Sublime syntax page](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html), the regex format is [Oniguruma Regular Expressions Version 5.9.1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kkos/oniguruma/5.9.6/doc/RE).